# If a CPU is always executing instructions how do we measure its work?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture

Let us say we have a fictitious single core CPU with Program Counter and basic instruction set such as Load, Store, Compare, Branch, Add, Mul and some ROM and RAM.  Upon switching on it executes a program from ROM.

Would it be fair to say the work the CPU does is based on the type of instruction it's executing. For example, a MUL operating would likely involve more transistors firing up than say Branch.

However from an outside perspective if the clock speed remains constant then surely the CPU could be said to be running at 100% constantly.

How exactly do we establish a paradigm for measuring the work of the CPU?  Is there some kind of standard metric perhaps based on the type of instructions executing, the power consumption of the CPU, number of clock cycles to complete or even whether it's accessing RAM or ROM.

A related second question is what does it mean for the program to "stop". Usually does it just branch in an infinite loop or does the PC halt and the CPU waits for an interupt?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, that a CPU is always executing some code is just an approximation these days. Computer systems have so-called sleep states which allow for energy saving when there is not too much work to do. Modern CPUs can also throttle their speed in order to improve battery life.

Apart from that, there is a difference between the CPU executing "some work" and "useful work". The CPU by itself can't tell, but the operating system usually can. Except for some embedded software, a CPU will never be running a single job, but rather an operating system with different processes within it. If there is no useful process to run, the Operating System will schedule the "idle task" which mostly means putting the CPU to sleep for some time (see above) or jsut burning CPU cycles in a loop which does nothing useful. Calculating the ratio of time spent in idle task to time spent in regular tasks gives the CPU's business factor.

So while in the old days of DOS when the computer was running (almost) only a single task, it was true that it was always doing something. Many applications used so-called busy-waiting if they jus thad to delay their execution for some time, doing nothing useful. But today there will almost always be a smart OS in place which can run the idle process than can put the CPU to sleep, throttle down its speed etc.

Comment: A processor can also stall waiting for memory (or even on high latency instruction). Useless work is also possible with branch (mis)prediction (the prediction that an instruction will not generate an exception is equivalent to branch prediction).

Answer (score 3):

Oh boy, this is a toughie. It’s a very practical question as it is a measure of performance and efficiency, and also a very subjective question as it judges what instructions are more or less “useful” toward accomplishing the purpose of an application. The purpose of an application could be just about anything, such as finding the solution to a complex matrix equation or rendering an image on a display.

In addition, modern processors do things like clock gating in power idle states. The oscillator is still producing cycles, but no instructions execute due to certain circuitry being idled due to cycles not reaching them. These are cycles that are not doing anything useful and need to be ignored.

Similarly, modern processors can execute multiple instructions simultaneously, execute them out of order, and predict and execute which instructions will be executed next before your program (i.e. the IP or Instruction Pointer) actually reaches them. You don’t want to include instructions whose execution never actually complete, such as because the processor guesses wrong and has to flush those instructions, e.g. as due to a branch mispredict. So a better metric is counting those instructions that actually complete. Instructions that complete are termed “retired”.

So we should only count those instructions that complete (i.e. retire), and cycles that are actually used to execute instructions (i.e. unhalted).)

Perhaps the most practical general metric for “work” is CPI or cycles-per-instruction: CPI = CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.CORE / INST_RETIRED.ANY. CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.CORE are cycles used to execute actual instructions (vs those “wasted” in an idle state). INST_RETIRED are those instructions that complete (vs those that don’t due to something like a branch mispredict).

Trying to get a more specific metric, such as the instructions that contribute to the solution of a matrix multiple, and excluding instructions that don’t directly contribute to computing the solution, such as control instructions, is very subjective and difficult to gather statistics on. (There are some that you can, such as VECTOR_INTENSITY = VPU_ELEMENTS_ACTIVE / VPU_INSTRUCTIONS_EXECUTED which is the number of SIMD vector operations, such as SSE or AVX, that are executed per second. These instructions are more likely to directly contribute to the solution of a mathematical solution as that is their primary purpose.)

Now that I’ve talked your ear off, check out some of the optimization resources at your local friendly Intel developer resource, software.intel.com. Particularly, check out how to effectively use VTune. I’m not suggesting you need to get VTune though you can get a free or very discounted student license (I think). But the material will tell you a lot about increasing your programs performance (i.e. optimizing), which is, if you think about it, increasing the useful work your program accomplishes.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Michał's answer a bit:

Program written for modern multi-tasking OSes are more like a collection of event handlers: they effectively setup listeners for I/O and then yield control back to the OS. The OS wake them up each time there is something to process (e.g. user action, data from device) and they "go to sleep" by calling into the OS once they've finished processing. Most OSes will also [preempt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) in case one process hog the CPU for too long and starve the others.

The OS can then keep tabs on how long each process are actually running (by remembering the start and end time of each run) and generate the statistics like CPU time and load (ready process queue length).

And to answer your second question:

To stop mostly means a process is no longer scheduled and all associated resource (scheduling data structures, file handles, memory space, ...) destroyed. This usually require the process to call a special OS call (syscall/interrupt) so the OS can release the resources gracefully.

If however a process run into an infinite loop and stops responding to OS events, then it can only be forcibly stopped (by simply not running it anymore).